# What are risks or disadvantages in uploading to figshare or related services?

Tags: publications, online-resource, open-access

[Figshare](http://figshare.com/) lets researches publish figures and data for long-term archival and public access. I just found out about it and find the idea sympathetic. See for example [their F.A.Q.](http://figshare.com/faqs).

What risks are involved with publishing my data and figures at figshare? What are the disadvantages? Did anyone actively decide *against* doing so, and if so, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, some journals have a "no prior publication" rule in place. These rules often preclude publishing anything that has already appeared in online databases that are freely accessible, so publishing figures in advance of a publication in a medium like this *could* be construed as violating such a policy. Since anything publicly posted gets published under a CC-BY license, so this almost assuredly counts with those journals as "prior publication."

In addition, anything that could be considered "confidential" or "proprietary" information definitely should not be posted on such a site until you have secured the necessary permissions from project partners and affiliates. That would also apply to "private" hosting of the figures.

Your own university or research institution may have policies that have some bearing on the ability to use such sites, so check with them as well. Better safe than sorry.

(Note: Those cautions aside, I *do* think it's a clever idea, and I hope it can catch on!)

Comment: With regards to prior publishing, F1000 research has looked into this (http://f1000research.com/about/?utm_source=jrnlbtn) in some detail and found the following journals are okay with it:
  
BMC journals  
BMJ Group journals  
Elsevier journals  
IOS Press journals 
The Lancet journals
Nature-titled journals
PLoS journals
RSC journals
SAGE journals
Adv Clin Neurosci Rehabil
Bioinformatics
Cardiovasc Ther
Ecol Lett
Eur J Neurosci
Int J Eat Disord
Int J Obstet Anesth
J Clin Invest
J Neurol
J Neurosci
J Pain
J Plant Ecol
Neurourol Urodyn
New Engl J Med
Proc Natl Acad Sci USA
PROTEOMICS J
Science