# ePrint Archive for PhD Dissertation in the Social Sciences

Tags: repository

I understand there are a number of specialised ePrint archives or repositories where scholarly works could be posted for wider dissemination (for example, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/)).

I am wondering if there is a preferred one for PhD dissertations in the social sciences?

Comment: Related question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84/preprint-services-other-than-arxiv-for-other-fields

Comment: http://www.ssrn.com/

Comment: Did you check with the library of your institution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish an eprint of your dissertation in [Researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net).

Comment: How does researchgate.net work?  It looks like it's just a social network aimed at researchers.  In that case, publishing an eprint there is not so different from just putting it on your own web page.  Putting something on the arXiv carries quite a bit more weight: it gets archived and maintained independently of you (or a social network that may not last), and far more people look at arXiv postings than any academic social network.

Comment: Of course arXiv is so much more efficient than social networks. But researchgate also offers an opportunity to follow the work of other members. For example if you follow a researcher, every time he publishes an article researchgate sends you a notification email. It also sends general notifications about recent articles related to your work every week. Besides researchgate is the only place that I know every researcher (from every discipline ) can post his/her articles.

Comment: I don't think a social network site should be used for primary archiving of a dissertation. Put it there as well sure, that might help disseminating it, but there is no guarantee of the quality of archiving there.

Answer (score 8):

You can always put a copy of your dissertation on your professional web page.  Google will find it.

Answer (score 5):

Your university is likely to have an institutional repository. This is probably the most important place to lodge an electronic copy of your dissertation and should definitely be used.

However, but it won't hurt to lodge the manuscript in other places. As others have noted, there are various ad-hoc options here (e.g. commercial networks like Academia.Edu and ResearchGate, your personal webpage, etc.).

To the best of my knowledge, there is no open access repository for the social sciences that has the same recognition as ArXiv. However, there are a few repositories like [SSOAR](http://www.ssoar.info), [SSRN](http://www.ssrn.com/en/), [EconStor](http://www.econstor.eu/?langselector=en) and [HAL-SHS](http://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/index.php?langue=en) that are becoming more widely used.

Comment: Besides SSOAR, I think [SSRN - Social Science Research Network](http://www.ssrn.com/en/), [EconStor](http://www.econstor.eu/?langselector=en) and [HAL-SHS](http://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/index.php?langue=en) are worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks @non-numeric_argument, I've modified my answer to include these.

Answer (score 2):

[Figshare](http://figshare.com/) is an easy and free option. It is not field specific. It has an backup archiving system. Submitted work tends to get indexed by Google and Google Scholar.

Answer (score 1):

One more recent place for this is [**SocArXiv**](https://socopen.org/2016/07/09/announcing-the-development-of-socarxiv-an-open-social-science-archive/), currently found [here](http://socarxiv.org), which was started in July 2016, so it is still in development. I'm not sure whether they will end up accepting theses or not (but, in principle, I'd go for a ¿why not? response), but it's worth a look.

Comment: There are certainly theses there at the moment, so that question seems solved :)