# Public archives for PhD thesis

Tags: thesis, arxiv, biology, repository

I am aware that PhD theses can be self archived in university site, personal webpage or sites like researchgate ([ePrint Archive for PhD Dissertation in the Social Sciences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/6115/39490)).

I am not really fond of researchgate. I wish to know if [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) (or [biorXiv](http://biorxiv.org/); as my field is biology that involves both mathematical modelling and experimental techniques) allows archiving of PhD thesis. This is not explicitly mentioned in these sites but [this](http://phd.fisica.unimi.it/students/theses/how-to-submit-a-phd-thesis-to-arxiv/) university site provides instructions on submitting PhD thesis to arXiv. I think this would be better than self archiving because arXiv submissions receive a DOI (I guess).

Does anyone have an experience with this? Are there other public repositories like arXiv that allow submission of PhD/masters theses (especially those that are biology related or accept all disciplines of science)?

Comment: One technical note: arXiv submissions do not actually receive a DOI; instead arXiv IDs are a separate system.  I don't think this matters (and I wouldn't recommend making your decision on this basis), but based on your comment I figured I'd mention it in case it matters to you for some reason.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Thanks for the clarification. Actually it doesn't matter but I think it would be better if the files have some kind of an index (arXiv IDs are fine).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it advisable to upload theses to the arXiv?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10451/650).

Comment: Are the chapters of your thesis being published in peer-review journals/conferences? If yes, you might not want to publish the same things in arXiv. Because, same results or claims should not be present in two different sites or sources.

Comment: @Coderif if preprints can be published then why not chapters of thesis that are perhaps equivalent to the preprints.

Comment: @WYSIWYG No, certainly don't post single chapters unless you have very good reasons for doing it. Post the thesis on its own, or not at all. I wouldn't be particularly worried by the duplication; it's generally understood that the thesis often contains material that has been or will be published elsewhere. (However, if you're too pushy with posting the thesis, that distinction gets slightly weakened.) You do need to check that any prospective publication venues are OK with you putting the thesis material online, though.

Comment: @E.P. No I did not mean posting chapters separately. I meant that if articles (which can be chapters of thesis) can be submitted in arXiv which can later/already be published elsewhere, then a consolidated thesis can also be submitted. It should not be considered as the "same thing being in two places". Many journals allow non-commercial archiving at any stage during the publication process. I just needed more details on this.

Comment: I believe archiving the thesis would allow better access to it (for the public). It seems arXiv supports it (JeffE said in the other liked post that it does) but I would like to know if there are other sites (especially biorXiv or others that are bio-related) allows this, or is there any other way to allow easy access to a thesis.

Comment: Seriously, the best place is your institution. If not, check bioRxiv's policies (from its [about page](http://biorxiv.org/about-biorxiv) it does have an emphasis on articles, but I can't find at the moment the equivalent page on the arXiv).

Comment: @E.P.: Archiving at the institution is usually required anyway.  But for a reader, *finding* a thesis archived at an institution tends to require navigating the institution's library catalog website, which is often arcane and idiosyncratic.  Given the choice, I'd much prefer to find a thesis on arXiv.