# Is there a pre-print server for building physics papers?

Tags: preprint

I recently submitted a pre-print (about heating control algorithms for buildings) to arXiv.org, under General Physics, but it was rejected as being off-topic for that server.

I tried to find a pre-print server specialising in Building Physics research but couldn't find any. [Wikipedia doesn't list anything.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprint#Preprint_server_by_research_field)

Is there a pre-print server that is suitable for that kind of publication?

Comment: Building physics?  Do you mean civil engineering?

Comment: Not necessarily. The journal I submitted the paper to is "Energy and Buildings" but I don't know if could call that civil engineering.

Comment: @lindelof I would consider most topics in this area to be closer to engineering than physics.

Comment: @lindelof This question may help you. [Preprint services other than arXiv (for other fields)](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84/preprint-services-other-than-arxiv-for-other-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't yet a pre-print server for building physics, although some people have successfully smuggled such papers onto arxiv.

Furthermore, there aren't really any heavyweight open-access building-physics journals, and established journals in the field haven't been quick to embrace open-access.

There is the option of producing internal working papers and circulating it without publication, to get some of the benefits of pre-print, without risking a publisher's refusal. However, it's not easy to reach a very broad audience this way, nor a new audience.

Building-physics papers do often span multiple subjects - we often cross-over, for example into health, for example, when we look at condensation and mould, radon, or dust mites; so there might be other pre-print archives that we can use.

And, although it's a completely different thing, there's always the possibility to air early thoughts on the building-physics tags on the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/building-physics) and [Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags/building-physics) Stack Exchanges, which can be a way to get a bit of an airing, and reach a different audience to that reached by circulation of working papers.