# Is there any recognized online portal where anyone can publish articles without being associated with any university or organization?

Tags: publications, mathematics, independent-researcher, physics, online-publication

Suppose some working person has interest in physics and mathematics and he want to publish a paper either review or research, so is there anyway he can publish? Obviously person is not associated with any university so he can not name that.

Comment: You don't need to be a member of a university or organization to submit a paper to journals. You can simply list your affiliation as "independent researcher."

Comment: A warning, which you may already be aware of: if a site or journal asks you to pay anything at all to publish your article, be very wary. There are legitimate journals that have page charges (which would normally be waived or reduced for an independent researcher with no research grants) but many pay-to-publish journals are total scams. By the time you're ready to publish, you'll probably have enough reputation on this site to ask about this in [chat] (you need 20+ rep).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, http://www.arxiv.org is the place for you.

But you can of course also publish in regular journals without being affiliated with a university. Science does not require a formal affiliation, just good ideas and data. If you have the latter, you can publish as a private citizen, an employee of a company, an employee of a government, or with any other background.

Comment: These days arXiv is decidedly not open to everyone. [You need either a history posting to the site, a affiliation that inspires confidence in the editorial board or a endorsement](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement). If the work is good getting an endorsement is a doable thing, but it's not trivial.

Comment: @dmckee Should arXiv reject you, then [viXra](http://vixra.org/) is for you. Just be aware that there is a small stigma of "crackpottery" from some scientists when regarding viXra submissions, because it (deliberately) has no quality standards.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I would say that calling the stigma "small" is an understatement. Many serious researchers consider the endorsement requirement for arXiv a minimal amount of effort that anyone who is actually interested in contributing to math research should be able to put in.

Comment: @dmckee It may not be trivial, but compared to actually writing a worthwhile paper, it is certainly a very minor thing (yes, even if it involves contacting a dozen different researchers in order to find someone who wishes to put in the time to read your work).

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: For what it's worth, I put a fair amount of effort into trying to get an endorsement a few years ago (for the manuscript I mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/elementary-papers-at-arxiv/50409#50409)), for example see this [1 June 2011 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7475298), and I finally gave up.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Sure, I am not surprised that it is hard to get endorsed for the general mathematics section, as that is a place very few research mathematicians publish, but the place with the largest amount of poor math. I must say that posting a reply to someone wanting to solve the Riemann hypothesis seems like a bad way to attempt to get endorsed. Usually I would recommend contacting someone who has written papers in a related area, but it is unclear if that would even be possible here.

Comment: Regarding my Feb 23 '16 comment, I happened to notice that the 2nd link I gave is now a dead URL. Using the Internet Archive's [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/), the following has a non-dead link: [*... see this 1 June 2011 sci.math post ...*](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206232233/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7475298)