# Websites to publish for mathematics and statistics similar to arXiv.org?

Tags: mathematics, arxiv, publishers, online-publication, statistics

What are websites similar to arXiv where there's feedback that one can submit to for Mathematics and Statistics?

Comment: Why not use arXiv?

Comment: See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37976/19607 for some other preprint servers.  I don't know if any of them have a feedback option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about statistics, but in mathematics it isn't common practice to post preprints to any website, which has any sort of feedback or commenting mechanism on the site itself. Such sites might exist, but they aren't in common use.