# Preprint services for environmental and earth sciences?

Tags: arxiv, preprint, science

Is there a good, reputable preprint service that is used in the environmental and earth sciences, and considered acceptable by the major publishers? Many journals specifically state that it is okay to submit a paper that has been uploaded to arXiv and I would like to take advantage of that, however I am not in a field covered by arXiv.

[I'm aware of the similar question, [Preprint services other than arXiv (for other fields)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84/preprint-services-other-than-arxiv-for-other-fields), but it is fairly old and there are no answers relevant to my field]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the following [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/asi.23021) ([open access version](http://www.openaccesspublishing.org/repositories/Subject_Repositories.pdf)) published in 2013 which lists 7 repositories for the earth sciences:

- CEDA Repository
- Earth-prints Repository
- Institution Aquatic Commons
- Organic Eprints
- AgEcon Search
- Open Knowledge Environment of the Caribbean
- antbase.org

I haven't checked the actuality of this list.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question was first asked, two repositories that are not in the answer above should be mentioned:

[Earth Arxiv](https://eartharxiv.org), run by the Open Science Framework, and the Earth and Space Science Open Archive [ESSOAr](https://www.essoar.org), which co-run by the American Geophysical Union.