# Repository for Education

Tags: thesis, repository

What would be the most appropriate place for someone to upload their Master thesis in Education? (Their institution does not upload electronic versions of theses.) The thesis is original research and a paper version has already been accepted to a conference; the author just wants to share their thesis with the community independently of the paper.

I have come across [this list](https://researchpreprints.com/preprintlist/) but I don't know the culture of the field, so I cannot advise them on which one to use, if any. I also note that the thesis is not in English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/)?

Comment: @corey979 As I mention in my question, the thesis is in Education. It has nothing to do with Math or Physics.

Comment: CERN operates an inder-disciplinary repository where everyone can upload content for free and that is easy to use. It's called Zenodo and the content will get a DOI: https://zenodo.org If you want a repository especially for education, I suggest to ask your question in a forum for education research.

Comment: Related: [Preprint services other than arXiv (for other fields)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84/17254). (There are a couple of potential candidates, but no obvious choice as far as I can tell. If a good choice for education research is found here, it should probably be mentioned in that question too.)

Comment: Unclear on why there are close votes here. This question seems very appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

As it seems unlikely at this point that this question will receive an appropriate answer soon, I'll answer my own question and give the best answer I came across.

Someone who is in Education research has told me that he and his colleagues use Academia.edu and ResearchGate. So, while there are certainly repositories out there, it would appear that they are not widely used. In the end, I recommended to the author of the thesis that they use these two sites.

Comment: I only recently joined the community so I was unable to answer this question, but I agree with who you consulted - ResearchGate and Academia.edu are common avenues, as well as Google Scholar. All are great options, and people tend to like them for different reasons. I have even seen undergraduate students publish their theses on Academia.edu and ResearchGate and receive a lot of support from the academic community, which has opened the doors for future collaboration and job prospects.

Answer (score 0):

> ...most appropriate place...to upload...Master thesis in Education? (Their institution does not upload electronic versions of theses.)

The technical report archive of the school or institute, a website you have via the school/institute, your personal website, or your supervisor's website.

> a paper version has already been
>   accepted to a conference

Given that it is published in some form, is there a need for the thesis itself? (Perhaps, because it probably contains additional material, but worth considering.)

As an alternative, maybe extend the conference version into a journal version.