# Arxiv did not accept my submission after being "on hold"

Tags: publications, paper-submission, arxiv, repository

I work in the field of Mechanics of Materials and my scientific papers are mostly about modeling. I have some preprints deposited on arxiv but I never submitted a preprint myself. This time, I did the submission myself (category of computational physics). However, after about 2 days, the paper status changed to "on hold". And after about five weeks of being on hold, they informed me that my paper will not be published. Here is the email:

> Dear author,
>
> Thank you for submitting your work to arXiv. We regret to inform you that
> arXiv’s moderators have determined that your submission will not be accepted
> and made public on[ |http://arxiv.org][arXiv.org|http://arxiv.org].
>
> Our moderators have determined that your submission is on a topic not
> covered by arXiv or that the intended audience for your work is not a
> community we currently serve.

Don't know what to do next. Should I resubmit? Are there any other legitimate repositories that I can try?

Comment: Maybe resubmit to a different category. Some of them are exclusive, some public. You need authorized permission for some of them. Is the publication associated with a university?

Comment: @apg If you mean my affiliation, it is not a university, rather a research institute.

Comment: Basically its probably based on something to do with the institute not being sort of "auto-recognized" by the arXiv moderators/subject moderators. Maybe try a different subject tag, or speak to the head of the institute/department and ask what they think?

Comment: Does your research institute have an option of posting your preprint on their site? I know, some math institutes do. Other than that, send the pdf file of your preprint to people who you think should be interested in it and submit your paper to a journal/conference proceedings, whatever appropriate.

Comment: Do you disagree with the conclusion that your preprint doesn't fit the topics covered? For other repositories, see [Preprint services other than arXiv (for other fields)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84/17254).

Comment: @Anyon Computational physics encompasses a broad range of topics, and I have seen so many papers on the same topic in arxiv.

Answer (score 3):

If you believe your article is actually on-topic for arXiv (check against the [category taxonomy](https://arxiv.org/category_taxonomy)), you can submit an [appeal](https://info.arxiv.org/help/moderation/appeals.html). Typically when you do so, you'll want to include what specific results are claimed in your work and how those results fit within the category you selected. If you wish for it to be considered for another area, be sure to explain why you feel its results better fit within that area instead.

Answer (score 2):

arXiv is famously very opaque when it comes to moderation, refusing to reveal their reasons for rejecting or putting papers on hold and rarely accepting appeals. There are many stories of established researchers getting their papers rejected without explanation. Some of them received coverage in [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2016.19267) or on [blogs run by leading scientists](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2022/02/04/submission-to-arxiv). You can find many verified accounts of such treatment on Twitter ([just one example](https://twitter.com/chaoyanglu/status/1425992656732123140)).

The moderators of arXiv are seemingly not accountable to anyone and it may be impossible to receive 'due process' from them.